# How do I have python check for a specific length to a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I was doing some homework and I'm kinda stumped. part of my assignment is that I need to have a If statement that checks if a number that was entered is 16 characters long or not, this is the code I have so far:

```
#the input
CreditCardNum = input("Input a credit card number(no spaces/hyphens): ")

#The if statements
if str(CreditCardNum) != len(16):
    print("This is not a valid number, make sure the number is 16 characters.")
elif str(CreditCardNum) == len(16):
    if str(CreditCardNum[0:]) == 4:
        print("The Card is a Visa")
    elif str(CreditCardNum[0:]) == 5:
        print("The Card is a Master Card")
    elif str(CreditCardNum[0:]) == 6:
        print("The Card is a Discover Card.")
    else:
        print("The brand could not be determined.")
```

Comment: And you do not get any errors "so far"? Such as "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()"?

Comment: I dont get it. Why on earth he will get that error?

Comment: @Rahul because he is trying to find the `len` of an object of type `int` even without converting it to a `str`?

Comment: Isn't this python? input will always return str weathr you type int float or whatever.

Comment: even this "`len(16)`" ?

Comment: @Rahul: rest assured, I did *not* make up that exact error string.

Comment: @Simpson: Did any of the solution worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the logic I believe you are looking for.

If card length is 16, it checks for the first character to determine which type.

```
CreditCardNum = input("Input a credit card number(no spaces/hyphens): ")

n = len(CreditCardNum)

if n != 16:
    print("This is not a valid number, make sure the number is 16 characters.")
else:
    x = CreditCardNum[0]
    if x == '4':
        print("The Card is a Visa")
    elif x == '5':
        print("The Card is a Master Card")
    elif x == '6':
        print("The Card is a Discover Card.")
    else:
        print("The brand could not be determined.")
```

**Explanation**

- Use `n = len(CreditCardNum)` to store in variable `n` the number of characters in the input string. Likewise first character of the input.
- `len(16)` makes no logical sense. You want to compare `n`, which is an integer, to another integer.
- To extract first letter of a string, simply do `mystr[0]`.

Comment: Not really - it's the first character that determines the issuer, not the length.

Comment: Two minor points: since x isn't needed unless the length is 16, you can assign it later, and that will guard against the string being empty; and, instead of `elif n==16`, a simple `else` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Python don't have switch function so you can either use `if elif` or `dictionary`.

Your case definately a dictionary type.

```
card_dict = {
    '4': "Visa",
    '5': "Master card",
    '6': "Discover card"
}
CreditCardNum = input("Input a credit card number(no 
spaces /hyphens): ")

n = len(CreditCardNum)
x = CreditCardNum[0]
if n != 16:
    print("This is not a valid number, make sure the number is 16 characters.")
elif x in card_dict:
    print("The Card is a {}".format(card_dict[x]))
else:
    print("The brand could not be determined")
```

Comment: On mobile so cant test but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try something like this:

```
#the input
CreditCardNum = input("Input a credit card number(no spaces/hyphens): ")

#The if statements
if len(str(CreditCardNum)) != 16:
    print("This is not a valid number, make sure the number is 16 characters.")
elif len(str(CreditCardNum)) == 16:
    if str(CreditCardNum[0]) == '4':
        print("The Card is a Visa")
    elif str(CreditCardNum[0]) == '5':
        print("The Card is a Master Card")
    elif str(CreditCardNum[0]) == '6':
        print("The Card is a Discover Card.")
    else:
        print("The brand could not be determined.")
```

I am not sure what you try to do in conditional statements within the outer `elif` but I am assuming you are trying to get the first character of your `CreditCardNum`?

Comment: `str(whatever)` will never be equal to an int (e.g., `4`)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `str(4) == 4` will always be `False`. You want `str(4) == '4'`

Comment: Sorry, don't know how I missed that part in the code. Thanks for the correction

Comment: would probably be more idiomatic to do `if CreditCardNum.startswith('4')`